# iOS simulator shows "sharp angles" instead of curves / pixelated zoom

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I can't seem to think of the word for this, but images in the iPhone simulator appear as though they were of a far lower resolution than they are. At 50% view, the simulator is already larger than the screen, but it is seen even worse at zoom level 25% and, strangely, it appears better in the 100% view, but still pixelated.

The high resolution image should zoom out accurately, but appears lower quality than the source image. It appears fine on the device and when viewing the source images.

25%[image]

50%

[image]

100%

[image: 100%]

Source Images:

At 1x:

[image]

[At 3x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr2CB.png)

Comment: I was going to resize the last image, but I realized that would defeat the purpose of it - anyways, it's very, very big an I would recommend removing it or having a smaller image that links to the full one. **Edit: nevermind, you read my mind :)**

Comment: Yes, the icons are too big. I should fix that, but it doesn't explain the difference between the device and the simulator (just in case anyone should think that) and with the iOS zoom feature. Images were with 5S simulator but appears similarly on 6+

Comment: I was talking about on the actual question, how the images were taking up too much of the page, but yes, you probably should include different sizes to reduce RAM usage. As for why they show up weird, it probably has to do with how you're scaling the image (and even then, I'm not sure, which is why I haven't answered)

Comment: If you scale the simulator, of course the images have less resolution and look bad. They have only 1/4 or 1/16 of the pixels...

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I would disagree with that. Although they may have 1/16 of the pixels, they are also being shown at 1/16 of the size, which means that that each pixel will be or at least could/should be the max possible DPI for the screen. Its a simulator issue definitely, partly related to their scale algorithm.

Comment: Its really annoying, but I know the simulator isn't exactly something that we can customize.

Comment: How do you disagree? If you leave out 15/16 of the pixels and only show 1/16, it will be jagged. They don't smooth it out or anything, just scale by dropping pixels. That's how it works and there shouldn't be an issue since it has no effect on any functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by going to Debug menu -> Graphics Quality Override -> High Quality and then restarting the simulator.

On 50% it looks fine now. It did not fix the 25% zoom issue, but I don't use that mode anyway.

Comment: The issue is still cosmetic. It doesn't affect anything in any way, except how you happen to see it on your screen.

Comment: "How I happen to see it on your screen" - lol - do you mean, how it appears to me on the simulator, which is what I was asking?...

Answer (score -1):

The reason why the 50% and 25% images look bad is because you're missing a lot of pixels. The simulator is always run at 100% and if you scale it they will just show every other pixel of every other row, or every fourth pixel of every fourth row. That's 75% or 94% of pixels just thrown away.

You can easily see this effect by scaling an image with nearest neighbor algorithm.

The reason why the 100% image looks jagged on simulator and not on device is because of the pixel sizes. If you take a magnifying lens and look at the phone, it will look as "bad", you just don't see it due to the size. Since you have to scale to 25% to get the full simulator to fit, you clearly don't have a huge resolution in screen, which means big pixels.

You shouldn't use overly big images anyway, since it will just consume memory and may produce unwanted artifacts.

Here is an example of your image resized to 50x50 pixels using nearest neighbor:
[image] and you can clearly see that it is totally jagged.

Comment: If I scale down the image above (1x) to 50px, it looks better than the image above 25% though being smaller. Images are scaled from algorithms of various quality, but in general, if you take an image of 100x100 and reduce it to 50x50, it will appear the same quality when shown at native size, as the lost pixels are not seen by the eye.

Comment: @user1122069 As I said, using nearest neighbor. It degrades to a very jagged image. If you remove pixels, it hurts the quality. If you don't use any smart algorithm, it doesn't look good. Otherwise we would just put 50x50px images on the web if they appeared the same quality as larger ones.

Comment: Thats great, however this was a question about how to get the screen to appear correctly, not a lecture about algorithms.